# how to know when application level variable is changed asp.net

Tags: asp.net, variables, onchange, global-asax, notify

I have application level variable stored in a cache in *global.asax* file:

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Application.Lock();
        List<MyClassName> myobjects = new List<MyClassName>();
        HttpContext.Current.Cache["List"] = myobjects;
        Application.UnLock();        
    }
```

And I access it and change it in a page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<MyClassName> myobjects = (List<MyClassname>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["List"];
   //change myobjects...
   HttpContext.Current.Cache["List"] = myobjects;
}
```

**Question is:**
*Suppose we have two users(browsers) running this site at the same time (for example they are chatting). How to notify another user when one user changes *myobjects* variable?*

We could check myobjects and compare this with old one periodically using timer. But it is not the best way.

*So is there better way to notify another user when global variable is changed?*

Comment: It is interesting, however, can you pls explain how do you manage to raise an event or notification in your application itself that the value has changed and so and so number of users need to be notified ? - Actually notifying the user is a different story

Comment: Every application will have timer inside and this timer periodically access global variable and makes copy, after some time timer again access the global variable and compares this old copied one. if they differ timer updates page or do other operations. So every users checks any changes itself. But it is not best way.

Answer (score 1):

For a webserver,considering the statelessness of http protocol, there is nothing like user or connected user, just a request and its response. When you say,  you want to notify a user, you are trying to say that server will initiate the communication which is not possible.

An idea could be, you could use long-polling, i.e. keep the request continuously alive and whenever you want to notify something to user, you feed in the data but again it is not a scalable solution - at least for low resource servers (of course google can afford it)

In order to notify anything, there user must be connected to the server - i.e. the communication must be initiated from client end.

Another alternative is,  using sockets. You could write a custom server and make your web application notify the custom server that the value has changed. The custom server in turn will notify the clients using sockets (Web sockets). This is rather complicated mechanism though. You could use websockets provided by html 5 or use addons like flash/java to work out the socket communication.